# Iterate through arraylist using data from excel file

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

So I have a document on excel and I have a list of data saying how many people use x or y and how many times. So basically i have a column with people ID, a column with type (x and y) then a column saying how many times the people use x or y. I want to be able to iterate through the list without changing it so as it get the number of people using each type and i want the list to be sorted in ascending order or frequency. So I wanted to use a for loop to go through the list and put an if statement inside of it saying that if x, then another for loop to be able to group them by frequency.

The actual code I have is not good but I am really stuck on that and do not really know how to proceed :

```
 for(int i = 0; i < type1.size(); i++){
       if(events.get(i).isX()){
           for(int j = 0; j < /*max value of the data in the list*/; j++ )
  //here list should group all common frequency
       }
       else
//do same thing but for y
```

[Excel table eg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KszEG.png)

[QUESTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA3kY.png)

Comment: if youre using ArrayList you can use Collections.sort() method. If thats not enaugh build your own comparator.

Comment: I wanted to use that at the when once I was able to group the correct frequencies for each type. The thing is that, I do not know how to make it group the frequencies of a specific type together...I do not know how to complete that actual piece of code I wrote..@TomWellbrock

Comment: how about making a new Object Row(int id, String type, int amount). Then you make an ArrayList<Row>. Iterate through your xls. and filling up the list. afterwards you can easely sort it as mentioned above.

Comment: I did not really understand how it becomes easier to group the same frequencies together when doing that @TomWellbrock

Comment: It would be much easier for me to answer you question if you could provide me some better code. Also I'd like to se an example of your excel and better formulations on your actual question. You said, that you have three columns I have no idea what you want to match together.

Comment: @TomWellbrock so I uploaded an example of a possible excel file and a question similar to what I am asking for. I do not have the exact question of what i am trying to do since i'm trying to learn sorting kind of...

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you have an excel-file with three columns:

```
id | type | frequency
```

And a List representing the data of your excel-file. You might want to order your Entrys with the `Collections.sort(Comparator<T>)` method.

Here is an example on how you can achieve that:

*Example a*:

```
Arraylist<Row> yourList = new ArrayList();
fillListWithExlData(yourList);

for(int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++){
    Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<Row>()){
    //compares row i with the following row
    compare(Row oneRow, Row followingRow){
    //if the result is 1 =< the entry moves on higher in the list if the result is = 0 it stays on its position and if its <= -1 it moves down.
    return oneRow.getFrequenzy() - followingRow.getFrequenzy();
    }
    });
}
```

Notice: that you can also use the Comparator to order your "types".

*Example b*:

```
return (oneRow.getType() == followingRow.getType()) ? 0 : -1;
```

Or you might even want to match both, id and frequency. Then you might try this:

*Example c*:

```
return (oneRow.getType() == followingRow.getType() &&  
        oneRow.getFrequenzy() == followingRow.getFrequenzy())
        ? 0 : -1;
```

example *a* should Order a potential List:

```
id | type | frequency
1  |  x   |    12
2  |  y   |    10
3  |  x   |    12
```

into:

```
id | type | frequency
1  |  x   |    12
3  |  x   |    12
2  |  y   |    10
```